# Preload Model Associations On Find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Right now I am trying to call my model, and spit out its results into json/xml format. My only problem is, my database associations aren't being loaded or queried.

Normally, I can just run this

```
@campaign = Campaign.find(:all)
```

Then get the number of hits by calling, `@campaign[0].hits` through the `has_many :hits`.

But if you debug the output, it only calls the columns on the table. How would you go about having it put it alongside your query?

In example:

```
  <campaign>
    <category>website</category>
    <created-at type="timestamp">2009-01-24 14:49:02 -0800</created-at>
    <end-at type="date">2009-01-24</end-at>
    <id type="integer">14</id>
    <is-watched type="integer">1</is-watched>
    <name>Lets</name>
    <slug>c5334415da5c89384e42ce6d72609dda</slug>
    <start-at type="date">2009-01-24</start-at>
    <user-id type="integer">5</user-id>
  </campaign>
```

Then having it instead add another column, but witht he number of hits.

```
  <campaign>
    <category>website</category>
    <created-at type="timestamp">2009-01-24 14:49:02 -0800</created-at>
    <end-at type="date">2009-01-24</end-at>
    <id type="integer">14</id>
    <is-watched type="integer">1</is-watched>
    <name>Lets</name>
    <slug>c5334415da5c89384e42ce6d72609dda</slug>
    <start-at type="date">2009-01-24</start-at>
    <user-id type="integer">5</user-id>
    <hits type="integer">123412</hits>
  </campaign>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ActiveRecord find() family takes an :include option which allows you to eager load your associatons.

So all you need to do is:

> @campaign = Campaign.find(:all,
>   :include => :hits)

The above will eager load your database calls so that accessing each index [0]. [1], etc wont issue their own SELECT calls. When you call

> @campaign[0].to_json

Then it will NOT include any associations, such as "hits" to do that then you also need to :include it on the to_json call, e.g.

> @campaign[0].to_json(:include => :hits)

Comment: That does what I asked, but is it possible to not return the rows, but to just count them, and return the integer?

Comment: Yes. ActiveRecord returns an AssociationProxy (which acts like an Array but has more super-powers). One method that it has is "size()". So you could do 

@campaign = Campaign.find(:all, :include => :hits)
@campaign.each do |cpg| 
  puts "Hits: #{cpg.hits.size}"
end

Comment: AssocationProxy has "count", "size" and "length", covered here:

http://rhnh.net/2007/09/26/counting-activerecord-associations-count-size-or-length

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to add the to_json or to_xml right? Since this isn't adding it on as an array.

Maybe a better question is, how to do another query and throw that in as a new column. Like a custom method.

Comment: @Garrett to_json is just a method on all members of ActiveRecord::Base, so you can overwrite it if you wish.

Comment: @Garret, you might also look at the use of :method here if you only want to add the counts in. http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M000900

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you want here by adding a hits_count field to your Campaign model. This will get automatically updated when new associations are added.

Have a look at counter_cache in the ActiveRecord [Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) documentation